# Parse error: "syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION"

Tags: php

**Sample Code:**

```
Config.php:
class Config {
    public $serverIP = "1.1.1.10";
}

DB.php:
require_once "/home/mysite/PHP/Config.php";
class DB extends Config {
    //DB related functions here..
}

research.php:
require_once "/home/mysite/PHP/DB.php";
class research extends DB {
    // Using DB functions to retrieve information from the research tables.
}
```

On executing the research.php file, I am getting an error message saying:

```
 "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/mysite/PHP/research.php on line 1".
```

I have checked every possibility that may cause this error. But I couldn't fix it. I have checked few possibilities such as `require_once("filepath");` missing braces, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on line 1, which you didn't post

Be sure you have space  between `<?php` and first code

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify which parent class for research :-

```
class research extends <-- where is the parent class?
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. It was a typing error in my post. I have corrected it. Kindly please check once again and give your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/mysite/PHP/research.php on line 1"

This means somewhere on line 1 of the `/home/mysite/PHP/research.php` file, the parser expected a function  declaration (`T_FUNCTION` token) but instead saw a semi-colon (`;`).

A semi-colon inside of the class definition by itself (for one) will [cause this error](http://codepad.org/UAYifax4).

Answer (score 0):

A weird quirk about PHP is it doesn't like semicolons at the end of some blocks but others it is fine with. For instance, a semicolon after a class method gives an error, but after the class definition itself doesn't bother it.